# Precision/AccuracyGoal in FindRoot don't work

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I am trying to solve a system with two transcendental equations and an additional condition and it does not work the way I want it to.

I am using this table with coefficients

```
coeff = {-9.59079, -7.62064, 0.154122}
```

and the code for solving the system is

```
FindRoot[{Cos[x]/x == -coeff[[1]], 
    Cos[y]/y == -coeff[[2]], 
    x == y + coeff[[3]]/R}, 
   {{x, .01}, {y, .01}, {R, .1}}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> Infinity][[1, 2]]
```

Now you can see that I used `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity` hoping the error would vanish, but it does not! The error saying:

*The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified \
by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient \
decrease in the merit function. You may need more than \
MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.*

Is still there. I even tried with `PrecisionGoal`, changing `MachinePrecision` and nothing works. I am loosing my mind here.

EDIT:
In case this is useful information: The initial values I gave 1/100 and 1/10 are simply my guess based on nothing actually.

Comment: I simplified the example to get rid of bits of code which are ancillary to the actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you rearrange the problem as follows (using `R(x-y) == c` instead of `x-y == c/R`):

```
FindRoot[{Cos[x]/x == 9.59079, 
  Cos[y]/y == 7.62064, 
  R (x - y) == 0.154122},
{{x, 0.01}, {y, 0.01}, {R, 0.1}},
AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]
```

Mathematica tells you there is a singular Jacobian at the point given. Essentially, Mathematica finds roots by constructing a suitable hill for which the bottom of the hill corresponds to a root, and then rolling down it. If the hill happens to have a flat bit somewhere, and you specify that you want it to start from the flat bit, then the rolling won't get you anywhere. Mathematica didn't happen to notice that this would happen, in your formulation, so it just spat out that it couldn't find a solution; my slight rearrangement allowed Mathematica to realise the problem and tell me what it was.

If you change `y` from `0.01` to `0.05`, it finds an answer - basically manually changing the starting point to one where the hill is not flat any more. Of course, Mathematica complains that it couldn't meet the accuracy requirements, because you asked it for infinite accuracy. Instead, ask it to find only `$MachinePrecision` amounts of accuracy (by removing the `AccuracyGoal`), and it becomes happy with its answer.

If you want more precision from your answers for some reason, you're going to have to increase the precision of your inputs as Nikolay Gromov points out, by using `SetPrecision` on `coeffs` and by using exact starting points `1/100, 5/100, 1/10` rather than `0.01, 0.05, 0.1`. Once you've done that, you can specify a larger `AccuracyGoal`.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have the same problem again (encountered singular jacobian). Same equation, same problem, only different numerical values.
My question is: How did you find out that I have to change y from 0.01 to 0.05? Were you only trying or is there a nice mathematical way to see that?

Comment: @skrat It was a guess. I'd imagine that most possible choices would work, though: unless your problem is peculiarly horrible, I'd have thought the Jacobian shouldn't be singular in very many places.

Comment: Was it also a guess that `y` was the right parameter to change or did you somehow know that?

Comment: @skrat Also a guess.

Comment: That's bad news for me! :) Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

There are several things to change. First, having `AccuracyGoal` bigger than  the working precision does not make sense so also change `WorkingPrecision -> 100` and also you may need `MaxIterations -> 100`. Second, your coefficients has a limited precision. You should do

```
coeff = SetPrecision[coeff,100]
```

And finally change all approximate numbers 0.01 and 0.1 to exact 1/100 and 1/10.
And change the starting point for R  `{R, -1/10}`

Result is:

```
{Cos[x]/x + coeff[[1, 1]], Cos[y]/y + coeff[[1, 2]], -x + y + coeff[[1, 3]]/R} /. fr
(*{0.*10^-80, 0.*10^-80, 0.*10^-81}*)
```

Comment: This is not the answer. Even working with all exact inputs, the problem is that there is a singular Jacobian: `FindRoot[{Cos[x]/x == Rationalize[9.59079], 
  Cos[y]/y == Rationalize[7.62064], 
  R (x - y) == Rationalize[0.154122]}, {{x, 1/100}, {y, 1/100}, {R, 
   1/10}}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`

Comment: It is solution, see the output above (one should also change starting points)

Comment: "One should also change starting points" - that is the answer. Yes, it makes no sense to have `AccuracyGoal` bigger than working precision. However, none of the rest of what you've written is necessary.

Comment: The question was about getting the result with decent accuracy. Without modifications I listed you will never get more then 15 digits. (Giving me -1 and posting another answer is not nice btw)

Comment: your answer misses the point of the question! The reason the OP's code wasn't converging was because of the initial conditions, and is nothing to do with the precision. If you work entirely with machine precision, setting a different initial condition, and still specify `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity`, it provides a good answer to machine precision, and complains that it couldn't get enough precision. If you use OP's code, it doesn't provide a good answer at all. OP wanted a way to find an answer, not to improve the precision of a spurious answer.

Comment: I think my solution also mentions the starting points no? 1 min before you posted your solution

Comment: Yes, it does, as an afterthought. You haven't explained why the starting points are important, and you give the strong impression that the important part is the use of machine precision. (You devote eight words to the actual reason, and fifty-three to tangential discussion of precision.)

Comment: I think you'll agree our answers are extremely different in flavour - timing of post is unimportant when one person is not simply stealing another person's idea.

Comment: How number of words could change the fact that I posted the correct solution first and got -1 form the one who changed the wording and reposted it again? That's not appropriate, my friend. The question title clearly indicates that the precision is also an important part of the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28989/discussion-between-patrick-stevens-and-nikolay-gromov).